# Input box vba displaying cell number instead of value

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code which prompts the user to click on a cell value.

```
Dim sDate As Range
On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Set sDate = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
            "Please select start date.", _
                Title:="Start Date", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    If sDate Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        sDate.Font.Bold = True
    End If
End Sub
```

The input box however once a value is selected lets say for example I click on b3 displays $b$3. I want to display the value that's inside $b$3. For example if 17-Jun was inside $b$3 it should display 17-Jun and not $b$3 in the input box.

Comment: You cannot do that with Type:=8, it will display the address.  Also consider what happens if a user selects more than 1 cell.

Comment: I'm just trying to select 1 cell no more. I understand I did range but how is it reworked to single cell? and does Type:=2 display that after I switch to single cell?

Comment: why did you omit the sub name from your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another answer is to use a UserForm.

Create a userform, such as this:

[image]

Notes: The "Ok" button is named "Ok", and the white text box is "dateBox"

For the Form Code, use:

```
Private Sub Ok_Click()
ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
UserForm1.Hide
End Sub
```

Then in the *Worksheet* module, put this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then UserForm1.dateBox.Value = Target.Value
End Sub
Sub bold_Date2()
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

Then run the `bold_date2()`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I understand that you need to take input from user, and assuming that only single cell will be provided. And you need to retrieve selected cell's value and set it's font style to bold.

You can achieve this by first get selected cell reference, use `Font` property to set any font styles and read its `Value` property to get its content.

```
 Set sDate = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
            "Please select start date.", _
                Title:="Start Date", Type:=8)

    sDate.Font.Bold = True
    MsgBox ("Selected cell's value is: " & sDate.Value)
```

Comment: I don't really want to ouput a message box I just want to display what they clicked on inside the input box. I understand what you explained though and makes sense for anyone trying to do it that way.

Comment: OK, then whats the problem. By using MsgBox I just tried to show, how you can get value from cell, i.e. `sDate.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

How does this work for you?

```
Sub bold_Date()
Dim sDate   As Range
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set sDate = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select start date.", Title:="Start Date", Type:=8)

If sDate.Cells.Count > 1 Then Set sDate = sDate.Cells(1, 1)
MsgBox ("Date is: " & sDate.Text)

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

If sDate Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    sDate.Font.Bold = True
End If
End Sub
```

It will put a messagebox with the date, after selecting a range.  Also, it has a check for multiple cells. If multiple cells are selected, it uses the first cell in that range as your new `sDate`.

Comment: Thank You, but I am just trying to put what the user clicked on inside the input box, it already does that but what it puts inside the input box the format is wrong.

Comment: @AngatvirSanghera - AFAIK that's not possible with `InputBox`.  You might be able to do that with a userform.